# d3js switching to version 4 : can't change node and node neighbors radius on click anymore

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to switch some code from d3js version 3 to version 4.
The graph gave the possibility to change node and connected nodes opacity and radius on click. However, as node'circle are not defined the same way on version 4, radius are not to be changed the same way. Here is the changes performed:

```
 var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append('g')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        //.attr('r', 15) 
        //.style('fill', function(d) {
        //   return color(d.degree);
        //})
        .call(d3.drag()
           .on('start', dragstarted)
           .on('drag',  dragged)
        )
        .on('click', connectedNodes);

  node.append('circle')
     .attr('r', 15) 
     .style('fill', function(d) {
        return color(d.degree);
     });
```

and here is the function used to change node and its neighbors on click:

```
function connectedNodes() {
        if (toggle == 0) {
           var d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
           node.style("opacity", function(o) {
              return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.3;
           });
           node.attr('r', function(o) {
              return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 20 : 15;
           });
           link.style("opacity", function(o) {
              return d.index == o.source.index | d.index == o.target.index ? 1 : 0.8;
           });
           link.style('stroke-width', function(o) {
              return d.index == o.source.index | d.index == o.target.index ? 3 : 0.8;
           });
           toggle = 1;
      }
 }
```

the block `node.attr('r', function(o)` does not work anymore (as opposite as `node.style('opacity, function(o)`) as the circles are not defined the same way.

How can I still update node and connected nodes radius on click ? I have seen some examples on how to do this but none applied as I want not only clicked node to be bigger, but also connected ones, and I don't know how to retrieve circle property from node attributes.

[here](https://pastebin.com/xzHJmD4Z) is the complete html (javascript embedded), and [here](https://pastebin.com/kySzR6K0) is the graph.json which is used by the script. Both on the same folder, and `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` to serve these files.

Many thanks!

I have tried to hardcode a higher value, regardless of neighboring, still no change, value not taken into account.

```
node.attr('r', function(o) {
   //   return neighboring(d, o) || neighboring(o, d) ? 20 : 15;
   return 25;
});
```

Comment: why do you use the bitwise OR `|` instead of the logical OR `||`? if you change the `r` on construction does it have effect? If so it is very strange that it does not work in the `connectedNodes`. How does it look in the DevTools? Can you change the `r` of a circle there?

Comment: Many thanks for answering! I have edited my question with links of the complete code on pastebin. I have changed ``|`` for ``||`` which seems more appropriate. Changing r on construction actually changes it on graph. I can also change r on DevTools (didn't know this feature, thanks ;)

Comment: what is the value for `r` or `opacity` of the nodes after you click using DevTools?

Comment: ``opacity`` is changing as expected, but ``r`` does not

Comment: what if you hard code a different r (40) in the click  handler?

Comment: same, no change. I have edited my question to present the changed line of my code. are you experiencing the same if you load my code from pastebin?

Comment: ``node.attr('r', 40);`` in the click handler produces the same :/ maybe i should try to change circle property instead of node property, but i don't know how to do it, ``console.log(node.circle)`` returns ``undefined``. I don't know how to get a handle on the circle (opacity seems to be node property, whereas radius circle property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you have ever been able to run the paste bin you show.

There are so many problems with `{}` and `()` that my browser refuses to run it.

- you have nothing beneath the `g` nodes so you replace them with the circles. `title` works as a child of `circle`, `text` isn't.
- what is an `div` with `weight:800px`?
- update the `cx` and `cy` of the circles, `transform` also works but this is neater.
- reset all the `node` `r` attributes for `toggle==1`

  ```
    var width = 800, height = 600;
    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
       .force('link', d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id;}).distance(100).strength(1))
       .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
       .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width/2, height/2));

    var svg = d3.select('#canvas').select('svg');
    if (svg.empty()) {
       svg = d3.select('#canvas').append('svg')
          .attr('width', width)
          .attr('height', height);
    }

    d3.json('graph.json', function(error, graph) {
       if (error) throw error;
       var links = graph.links, nodes = graph.nodes;
       var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
          .data(graph.links)
          .enter().append('line')
          .attr('class', 'link');

       var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
          .data(nodes)
          .enter().append('circle')
          .attr('class', 'node')
          .attr('r', 15)
          .style('fill', function(d) { return color(d.degree); })
          .call(d3.drag()
             .on('start', dragstarted)
             .on('drag',  dragged)
             .on('end',  dragended)
          )
          .on('click', connectedNodes);

    simulation
       .nodes(nodes)
       .on('tick', ticked);

    simulation.force('link').links(links);

     function ticked() {
      link
          .attr("x1", function (d) {return d.source.x;})
          .attr("y1", function (d) {return d.source.y;})
          .attr("x2", function (d) {return d.target.x;})
          .attr("y2", function (d) {return d.target.y;});

      node
          .attr("cx", function (d) {return d.x;})
          .attr("cy", function (d) {return d.y;})
      }

       function dragstarted(d) {
          if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
          d.fx = d.x;
          d.fy = d.y;
       }

       function dragged(d) {
          d.fx = d3.event.x;
          d.fy = d3.event.y;
       }

       function dragended(d) {
          if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
          d.fx = null;
          d.fy = null;
       }

       node.append('title')
          .text(function(d) {
             return "Node: " + d.id + "\n" + "Degree: " + d.degree + "\n" + "Katz: " + d.katz;
          });

       var toggle = 0;
       var linkedByIndex = {};
       for (var i = 0; i < graph.nodes.length; i++) {
          linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1;
       }
       graph.links.forEach(function(d) {
          linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
       });

       function neighboring(a, b) {
          return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
       }

       function connectedNodes() {
          if (toggle == 0) {
             var d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
             node.style("opacity", function(o) {
                return neighboring(d, o) || neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.3;
             })
                 .attr('r', function(o) {
                return neighboring(d, o) || neighboring(o, d) ? 20 : 15;
             });
             link.style("opacity", function(o) {
                return d.index == o.source.index || d.index == o.target.index ? 1 : 0.8;
             })
                 .style('stroke-width', function(o) {
                return d.index == o.source.index || d.index == o.target.index ? 3 : 0.8;
             });
             toggle = 1;
          } else {
             node.style('opacity', 1)
                 .attr('r', 15);
             link.style('opacity', 1)
                 .style('stroke-width', 1);
             toggle = 0;
          }
       }
    }
  );
  ```

Comment: Many thanks! This is working perfectly. js is totally new for me, and d3js might not be the easiest way to dive in. You helped me a lot having a better understanding of how this should work!